# How do I pass a standard set of parameters to each function in an async.js series?

Tags: node.js, middleware, async.js

Given the following node.js module, how would I call the functions in the array `orderedListOfFunctions` passing each one the `response` variable?

```
var async = require("async");
var one = require("./one.js");
var two = require("./two.js");

module.exports = function (options) {

var orderedListOfFunctions = [
    one,
    two
];

return function (request, response, next) {

    // This is where I'm a bit confused...
    async.series(orderedListOfFunctions, function (error, returns) {
        console.log(returns);
        next();
    });

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to do this like so:

```
module.exports = function (options) {
  return function (request, response, next) {
    var orderedListOfFunctions = [
      one.bind(this, response),
      two.bind(this, response)
    ];

    async.series(orderedListOfFunctions, function (error, resultsArray) {
      console.log(resultArray);
      next();
    });
};
```

The `bind` call prepends `response` to the list of parameters provided to the `one` and `two` functions when called by `async.series`.

Note that I also moved the results and `next()` handling inside the callback as that's likely what you want.

Comment: Quick question about optimization & repetition... There's no ideal way to do this without closing orderedListOfFunctions into the function?

Comment: @Omega Not if you want it to reference the call-specific `response`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK what' is 'this' referring to in one.bind(this, response) when the bind occurs?

Comment: @Vish `this` will be whatever context the exported function is called from. It's not actually important in this usage of `bind`, as the method is just being used prepend the `response` parameter to the function invocations.

Comment: @JohnnyHK this code will work if I also pass null. What's the context of this in the above example? Also, if I have to abstract the final anonymous callback function of async and bind response to it as well. Will that work?

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vchouhan/bzuj24q3/)

Comment: @JohnnyHK I tried what you have in your example but this solution didn't work as the callback fn didn't have any reference to the response param. The first 2 params when the async.series invoked the callback only had reference to err, result. I've left comments in your example.

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with OP's desire to do this without closing orderredListOfFunctions in the returned function:

```
var async = require("async");
var one = require("./one.js");
var two = require("./two.js");

module.exports = function (options) {

  var orderedListOfFunctions = function (response) {return [
      one.bind(this, response),
      two.bind(this, response)
   ];};

   return function (request, response, next) {
      async.series(orderedListOfFunctions(response), function (error, returns) {
         console.log(returns);
         next();
      });
   };
};
```

Comment: what's the context of this in the above implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Simple alternative is **applyEachSeries** -

```
applyEachSeries(tasks, args..., [callback])
```

Example -

```
function one(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // Do something
    return callback();
}

function two(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // Do something
    return callback();
}

async.applyEachSeries([one, two], 'argument 1', 'argument 2', function finalCallback(err) {
    // This will run after one and two
});
```