# How to make use of async.applyEachSeries in node js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Much appreciated if someone can give a more concrete example of how to use the async.applyEachSeries function.

```
async.applyEach([enableSearch, updateSchema], 'bucket', callback);

// partial application example:
async.each(
    buckets,
    async.applyEach([enableSearch, updateSchema]),
    callback
);
```

This is from the async readme documentation, but I have no idea how to use it. What is the 'bucket', is it just a string being passed to somewhere?

Comment: So you know, your code example uses `applyEach`, while your question title mentions `applyEachSeries`. I'm assuming you want to know about `applyEachSeries`, since they have the same usage.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.

Comment: Does my answer make sense regarding `applyEachSeries()`? The code snippets only used `applyEach()` and `each()`, though if you used `applyEachSeries` in this example it would simply execute the callbacks in order.

Comment: yea, it makes sense, but I still not understand it 100%, it will be a lot helpful if you can give a compete example with code. I copy and pasted this code snippets from https://github.com/caolan/async#applyEachSeries,

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want an example of. If you're looking for an example of `applyEachSeries()` instead of `applyEach()`, its usage would basically be the same as `applyEach()` (though it is ensured that the functions passed in the first parameter are executed in order). Were you looking for a more practical example of `applyEachSeries()`?

Comment: Yes, more practical example of applyEachSeries(). Having actual functions that are being passed into the applyEachSeries(), with input output. The functions being passed has to be async functions

Answer (score 6):

```
async.applyEach([enableSearch, updateSchema], 'bucket', callback);
```

This calls `enableSearch('bucket')` and `updateSearch('bucket')` asynchronously with callbacks, and then calls `callback()` once they are both done.

---

```
// partial application example:
async.each(
    buckets,
    async.applyEach([enableSearch, updateSchema]),
    callback
);
```

The `async.applyEach()` call returns a function that calls both `enableSearch()` and `updateSchema()` with its arguments when it is called. Since the first argument to `async.each()` should be an Array, I assume that `buckets` is an Array of Strings (as the first example involved passing one string to `enableSearch()` and `updateSearch()`). As a result, this could would call `enableSearch()` and `updateSearch()` with each String in the Array `buckets` (and then call `callback()`).

Comment: In my case, callback is not working. And `async.applyEachSeries` calling only first function `enableSearch` and no callback.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty clear example of async.applyEachSeries:

```
applyEachSeries(tasks, args..., [callback])
```

example:

```
function one(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // Do something
    return callback();
}

function two(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // Do something
    return callback();
}

async.applyEachSeries([one, two], 'argument 1', 'argument 2', function finalCallback(err) {
    // This will run after one and two
});
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35309495